# Selecting single row by ID in MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

It seems MonetDB still performs full table scans even where one record has to be pulled by some ID column.

`select a, b, c from mytable where id = 100;`

Is there anything that can be done to improve performance here? It doesn't seem like creating an index does anything in this case.

Comment: monetdb ignores indexes.  and its column-oriented nature makes a query like this expensive.  rather than pulling a single id, can you instead pull all of your needed `id` records at once?  something like `SELECT a , b , c FROM mytable INNER JOIN SELECT id FROM othertable ON mytable.id = othertable.id`

Comment: @Anthony I'm mainly using MonetDB for analytical queries and it works great, but need to implement getting a single record efficiently from the same table (300 mil records) by known record ID. It seems like I may need to use a different store for that.